# how to show existence of such a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Given that $E$ is an $m_1\times n_1$ matrix with $m_1\le n_1$ and $C$ is a $p_1\times n_1$ matrix. We are given that rank of $\begin{bmatrix}E\\C\end{bmatrix}=n_1$, then we need to show that there exists a full column rank matrix $R$ which is of $n_1\times m_1$ such that

rank of $\begin{bmatrix}I_{n_1}-RE\\C\end{bmatrix}=rank(C)$

Comment: For future reference you would improve posts by adding context.  Although the problem statement is clear enough, it's going to be a bit of guesswork for Readers to sort out where you may be having difficulty.  Any special cases, e.g. take $n_1 = 2$ and $rank(C) = 1$, would help to show context.

Comment: Why only for "future reference", @hardmath?  I see no reason why Wow cannot make an edit here, now, to include context.

Comment: @amWhy:  Yes, the very near future will do nicely.  However this particular user has been temporarily suspended, so some hours must pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us translate the mentioned properties. By the
rank-nullity theorem

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{rcl}\text{rank} \left[\begin{array}{c}E\\
C
\end{array}\right] = {n}_{1}&\Longleftrightarrow &{n}_{1}-\text{rank} \left[\begin{array}{c}E\\
C
\end{array}\right] = 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\dim  \text{ker} \left[\begin{array}{c}E\\
C
\end{array}\right] = 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\dim  \left(\text{ker} \left(E\right) \cap  \text{ker} \left(C\right)\right) = 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\boxed{\text{ker} \left(E\right) \cap  \text{ker} \left(C\right) = \left\{0\right\}}
\end{array}$$

and

$$\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}  \begin{array}{rcl}\text{rank} \left[\begin{array}{c}{I}_{{n}_{1}}-R E\\
C
\end{array}\right] = \text{rank} \left(C\right)&\Longleftrightarrow &\dim  \text{ker} \left[\begin{array}{c}{I}_{{n}_{1}}-R E\\
C
\end{array}\right] = \dim  \text{ker} \left(C\right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\dim  \left(\text{ker} \left({I}_{{n}_{1}}-R E\right) \cap  \text{ker} \left(C\right)\right) = \dim  \text{ker} \left(C\right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\text{ker} \left({I}_{{n}_{1}}-R E\right) \cap  \text{ker} \left(C\right) = \text{ker} \left(C\right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow &\boxed{\text{ker} \left(C\right) \subset  \text{ker} \left({I}_{{n}_{1}}-R E\right)}
\end{array}$$

Decompose

$${\mathbb{R}}^{{n}_{1}} = \text{ker} \left(C\right) \oplus  V \qquad  {\mathbb{R}}^{{m}_{1}} = E \left(\text{ker} \left(C\right)\right) \oplus  W$$

Remark that $E$ is one-to-one on $\text{ker} \left(C\right)$ because
$\text{ker} \left(E\right) \cap  \text{ker} \left(C\right) = \left\{0\right\}$. This implies that

$$\dim  W = {m}_{1}-\dim  \text{ker} \left(C\right)  \leqslant  {n}_{1}-\dim  \text{ker} \left(C\right) = \dim  V$$

We define $R \colon  {\mathbb{R}}^{{m}_{1}} \rightarrow  {\mathbb{R}}^{{n}_{1}}$ by choosing
${\left.R\right|}_{E \left(\text{ker} \left(C\right)\right)} = {\left({\left.E\right|}_{\text{ker} \left(C\right)}\right)}^{{-1}}$
and for ${\left.R\right|}_{W}$ we choose any one-to-one map from
$W$ to $V$.

As $R$ is one to one, it follows that $\text{rank} \left(R\right) = {m}_{1}$, as required.

Here is a Scilab example that explain how to compute a matrix $R$

```
E = [1 1 1 1; 3 1 2 1; 1 2 4 8]
C = [1 2 3 1; 0 1 2 1; 2 1 0 -1]
m1 = size(E, 1)
n1 = size(E, 2)
K = kernel(C)
k = size(K, 2)
L = kernel(K')
M = E * K
N = kernel(M')
P = [K L(:,1:m1-k)]
R = clean(P * inv([M N]))
S = [eye(n1,n1)-R*E; C]
rank(S)
```

The example uses the Scilab function `kernel()` that computes
a basis of the matrix's nullspace. The same function can be used to
compute a complemement of a subspace by taking the nullspace of
the transpose matrix (which is the orthogonal subspace).

Comment: All right, see my edit above. I was expecting you to tell us what you have tried...

Comment: I don't use Matlab, but see my edit with the Scilab example.

Comment: The keywords "scilab clean" typed in your favorite search engine lead you to [this page](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.3.3/en_US/clean.html) :)